# Uncaught TypeError Object has no method 'sortable'

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-sortable, typeerror

I've found a few fixes for this issue already but they aren't specific to this. I've read simple things like Sortable() needs to be lowercase. Of course, I do not have it set as uppercase first.

I already had this working and then suddenly it decided to spit out the following in the console `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable'` on line:210 which correspondes to:

```
    // Line 210 is below
    $('.sortable').sortable({
         stop: get_post_order
    }).disableSelection();
    // Check new order
    function get_post_order() {
        var post_list = [], pids;
        $('.inner-pop-list li a').each(function() {
            pids = $(this).attr('rel');
            post_list.push(pids);
        });
        $('.export').attr('href', '?format=pdf&pids='+post_list);
    }
```

It should be updating the post_list array after the list has been reordered. The `get_post_order` is not running at all. I've tried adding the function directly into the `stop: function() {...}` but still no change.

Any ideas, I'm pretty stumped.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your jquery and jquery-ui libaries are loaded correctly ?

Comment: Well, it was working before and I haven't changed anything with that part of the site. So yes I am pretty sure. I will triple check.

Comment: Everything looks fine there. The dragging event works, so I would guess that it is loading..

Comment: I had created a custom jQuery ui file only containing the elements I had chosen before I needed sortable. I had to add jquery.ui.sortable.js to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, sometimes getting fresh approaches from other people leads you to the answer. Thanks for your help. It made me look at the header of my site. I noticed I'd already added the sortable() declaration in the header. Then I'd referenced sortable again in an external script (which was line 210) causing a conflict.

So the answer is, reference sortable() once!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your javascript code is not within $(document).ready, and it is being executed before the ui library has loaded.

Comment: It seems that sortable is not defined, or not yet loaded.  I dunno, but it is a typical error when a jquery module is not loaded.  So, maybe your jquery-ui does not have the module (e.g. custom jquery-ui), or your code is run before jquery-ui is loaded.

Comment: I found the solution, see below. Thanks for everyone's time and comments.