# Why my MVC pattern doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I had written HTML code for Drag and Drop function, I received correct output. I've changed same code to MVC but I didn't receive the output, I mean drag and drop isn't works.It shows the following error:

> Uncaught Error sortable is not a function

Here is my code:

```
var startPosition;
var endPosition;

$("#datatable-wrapper #example tbody").sortable({
    cursor: "move",
    start:function(event, ui){
        startPosition = ui.item.prevAll().length + 1;
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        endPosition = ui.item.prevAll().length + 1;
        alert('Start Position: ' + startPosition + ' End Position: ' + endPosition);
    }
});
```

Comment: did you refer jquery-ui?

Comment: Yes Dude, please advise me further

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952353/uncaught-typeerror-object-has-no-method-sortable

Comment: My HtML code gives correct output, but when I change to MVC it shows error

Comment: did you refer jquery twise?

Comment: Yes my jquery has given output in HTML code, but when I change it to Zend Framework-MVC it doesn't work